# Flash User Interface without Flash?

Tags: interaction-design, web-app, flash

These are exciting times for developers that want to spread their wings with interactive-design. And I have a project forth coming that I wish to give the user a great experience every time they use the application. Flash is the perfect candidate for the experience I wish to give those users.

However, because of lack of love between Flash and Apple, I feel my hands are tied. Because this is a web service oriented application, that will serve thousands of customers, I am afraid that it will be to much strain on the server side to be a flawless user experience. Not to mention the amount of server resources it would take to generate the render the graphics on the fly. Throwing XML to the client would be optimum.

Mobile is a huge part in this game now as well, and that needs to be weaved in the mix as well. HTML5, CSS3, and company just doesn't cut it yet. Has anyone found a great solution to this transitional issue?

Comment: This is more of a discussion topic than an answerable question. Is there anything *specific* you want advice on?

Comment: Yes, a specific solution to a problem with Flash and Apple. To ask a question on how to make OSX work with Flash would be a debate. I just needed the alternative to Flash and get the same UX experience. And I got the answer...

Comment: I'm afraid you misunderstand the meaning of UX. What specifically are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: UX is a broad term used to explain all aspects of a person’s experience with the system including the interface, graphics, industrial design, physical interaction. I am trying to accomplish getting the same result from another technology other than Flash.

Comment: The only reason people used Flash for web design was animations. Everything else could be easily accomplished with the existing tools. Animations are bad UX for the most part because they distract from tasks & content consumption. Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: Exactly. Apple has done a great job in lightly combining animation and functionality to enhance the "UX". This project demands the same, as so do I. Using large data sets to render positive feedback and workflow is a killer on servers. With Flash all you have to do is send some XML to the client and the hard work is rendered there. I need a way to create graphical imagery on the client side, or invest in a few hundred racks. And I don't have a billion dollars to throw around like Facebook.

Comment: Animation is also a killer on mobile device's batteries. You're thinking in terms of visual gimmicks before information architecture and use cases. Instead, you should start with them and then *enhance* the experience with animations. However, you haven't narrowed down the scope of your question: there's a lot that can be done in Flash & replicated with other tools/frameworks/languages.

Comment: My servers your batteries. Specific Example: I need to render a 3D graphical image to display to the user using 2500 data sets each having 300 to 700 data points.

Comment: @Chad dnbrv is correct, you need to narrow down this question because there are multiple alternatives to various Flash implementations so we can't give you a full answer without knowing something more specific you want to know about. Also, claiming *"My servers your batteries"* gives the indication that you don't actually care at all about the User, you just want flashy gimmicks just for the sake of it.

Comment: @Chad: We aren't happy either that your first experience on UX.SE is bad. However, we have [certain rules about questions](http://ux.stackexchange.com/faq) here and in its current form your question doesn't fit. If you asked "How can I do X without Flash?" we would've helped you but you've asked "How can I do everything without Flash?" and that's impossible to answer because of the abundance of choices.

Comment: Yes, context is everything. Flash isn't a UX solution any more than it's a UX problem. It's simply a particular technology.

Answer (score 1):

Considering HTML5 and Jquery i would go with them instead of flash:

- ressource saving since client-side
- very smooth and versatile
- no flash needed
- HTML5 let you do things we dreamed of 2 years ago, google examples
- lot of opensource code to use

Comment: Thank you for your response! Are there some good specific examples to take a look at?

Comment: just google and you find them. eg http://html5demos.com/ or http://jquery.com/